# How can we harmonize Leviticus 23:18 & Numbers 28:27?

Tags: contradiction, leviticus, numbers

(KJV)Leviticus 23:18

> And ye shall offer with the bread seven lambs without blemish of the first year, and one young bullock, and two rams: they shall be for a burnt offering unto the Lord , with their meat offering, and their drink offerings, even an offering made by fire, of sweet savour unto the Lord .

(KJV)Numbers 28:27

> But ye shall offer the burnt offering for a sweet savour unto the Lord ; two young bullocks, one ram, seven lambs of the first year;

How can we reconcile the above texts since they seem to be talking of the same festival of weeks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer (Rabbinical interpretation): The one in Numbers is referring to the standard quota that was sacrificed on all the "Chodeshim" (new month) and the "Regalim" (pilgrimage on the holidays [Besides for Sukkot in which the sacrifices were prescribed in a different manner]). In all the aforementioned holidays the quota was "2 bullocks, one ram, seven lambs". Leviticus 23 on the other hand is referring to the special wave offering that was brought on "Shavuos", together with this offering it was required to bring another "bullock and two rams and seven lambs". These did not replace the quota of "2 bullocks, one ram, seven lambs" of every "Regel", but they were added to it with the wave offering.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you have any references for us?

Comment: see Maimonides (or Rambam) Hilchos Temidim Umusafim beginning of chapter 8. Fyi, i was gonna provide references in my answer but i don't know how to :(